# Mockito's Answer in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

Is there some alternative to Mockito's [Answer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) in ScalaTest? I was going through its [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects), but didn't find anything.

I would like to, for example, execute some logic on arguments of a stubbed method. In Mockito, I would do something like this:

```
when(mock.create(any(A.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        A firstArg = (A) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        firstArg.callMethod();
        return null;
    }
});
```

In ScalaTest, I'm fine with using Mockito, as well. However, it would be nice if there was some more Scala-friendly syntax of defining such `Answer`.

Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you let us know what exactly you find to be deficient.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific...

Answer (score 11):

I just found [this blog post](http://henningpetersen.com/post/10/using-mockito-answers-with-scala-2-9). It describes how to use implicit conversions to achieve what you want. If you define an implicit conversion like this

```
implicit def toAnswerWithArgs[T](f: InvocationOnMock => T) = new Answer[T] {
    override def answer(i: InvocationOnMock): T = f(i)
}
```

you can call `thenAnswer` with a simple function as argument:

```
when(mock.someMethodCall()).thenAnswer((i) => calculateReturnValue())
```

There is also a slightly shorter alternative version for the case when your mocked method has no arguments. Follow the link for details.

Comment: So much cleaner as, after adding the implicits, doReturn can be replaced directly with doAnswer when the return value need recomputation on request.

Answer (score 3):

Define this helper function:

```
def answer[T](f: InvocationOnMock => T): Answer[T] = {
  new Answer[T] {
    override def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): T = f(invocation)
  }
}
```

And use it like this, e.g. for returning a `Future[MyClass]` containing any argument passed to a method:

```
when(myRepository.create(any[MyClass]())).thenAnswer(answer({ invocation =>
  Future.successful(invocation.getArguments.head.asInstanceOf[MyClass])
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mix in the trait [MockitoSugar](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.9.1/#org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar), you can create a mock and and pass it an answer using this syntax:

```
mock[Collaborator](new Answer(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/2.x/index.html)?  It is also [integrated with ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects#scalamock) and provides a more Scala-friendly API.

Comment: I'm in the process of migrating from mockito to ScalaMock, and was wondering how one can actually do something like `InvocationOnMock` in ScalaMock. Turns out it was super easy and just like I would have wanted to do in mockito: just have some impure/mutative function that is wrappen in ScalaMock's `returns`: like `...when(...).returns(updateCount())`