# Scala Mockito: allow only certain (i.e. whitelist) methods to be called

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

How can I create a mock and "white list" only certain methods?

For example, if I have a trait Foo, I want to allow only calls to a() and b(), and disallow any other methods -- without explicitly blacklisting them.

```scala
trait Foo {
    def a()
    def b()
    def c()
    def d()
}

val mfoo = mock[Foo]
whitelist(mfoo.a, mfoo.b)
mfoo.c() // should fail since it's not whitelisted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do strict mocks with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003278/is-it-possible-to-do-strict-mocks-with-mockito)

Comment: @EyalRoth doesn't seem to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024352/mockitos-answer-in-scalatest

Comment: @solyd I am not sure what you meant by referencing that link, but if you think it says you can't use `Answer`, it is certainly not so: you very much _can_ use it.

Comment: @Dima I would love an example for my simple use case because I can't get it to work.

Comment: @solyd what exactly do you mean by "can't get it to work"? Did you try just doing what that SO answer suggests?

Comment: The issues I'm having cannot be expressed summarily enough to be included as a comment. It would take much less effort to provide an example :p

Comment: @solyd There are several answers in the question I referred to earlier. In general, you have to ways of approaching this: (a) create a mock with a default answer that throws an exception and stub the "white list" methods; or (b) verify that the "white list" methods were invoked `atLeast(0)` and then `verifyNoMoreInteractions` on the mock.

Comment: @solyd you don't need to include them in a comment. Just update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity's sake:

You can use `verify(mfoo, atLeast(0)).a()` to allow zero or more invocations of method `a()`, thus whitelisting it.

```scala
trait Foo {
    def a()
    def b()
    def c()
    def d()
}

val mfoo = mock[Foo]

// ... test code ...

// whitelisting a() and b() is equivalent to:
verify(mfoo, atLeast(0)).a()
verify(mfoo, atLeast(0)).b()

// everything else is blacklisted by default:
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mfoo)
```

p.s. You can also hook into any invocation on the mock object by using the `Answer` construct ([Mockito's Answer in ScalaTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024352/mockitos-answer-in-scalatest)), but I was not successful in doing so in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use strict mode with [mockito-scala-scalatest](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#strict-mode), when you work in strict mode any method you don't stub/verify and it's called by your code will make the test fail with an exception stating you shouldn't be calling said method

Answer (score 0):

When I used Mockito I used the [verifyNoMoreInteractions()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions-java.lang.Object...-).

You can stub your mock and then you can verify that no other invokation has happened.

In the current version there are also other verifications methods. Have a look [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#7).

Comment: This doesn't not solve my problem as `verify(x).foo()` is equivalent to `verify(x, times(1)).foo()`. I want to merely allow invocation of `foo`, not ensure it was called at least once.

Comment: I don't see the problem: `val m= mock[Foo]; m.a(); m.b();  m.c(); verify(m, atLeastOnce(),).a(); verify(m, atMostOnce()).b();verifyNoMoreInteractions(m) // <- this should fail as c() is called`

Comment: @thopaw the problem is this will fail if `a()` is not called

Comment: @thopaw Use `atLeast(0)`.